# Making ogr2ogr convert from CSV to SpatiaLite while keeping capital letters on the header

Tags: csv, ogr2ogr, spatialite

Let's say I have the following `input.csv` file:

```
Column1,Column2,latitude,longitude
testData,TestData,-23.547384,-46.643363
testData,TestData,-23.555297,-46.635642
```

I know I can convert it from CSV to SpatiaLite with the command:

```bsh
ogr2ogr -f "SQLite" -dsco SPATIALITE=YES -oo X_POSSIBLE_NAMES=longitude -oo Y_POSSIBLE_NAMES=latitude output.sqlite input.csv
```

However, even though the SpatiaLite database is successfully created, when I look to the column headers I see the following:

[image]

Here `column1` and `column2` are not as the original file (`Column1` and `Column2`). Is there any way of preserving the capital letters on the header while converting from CSV to SpatiaLite with `ogr2ogr`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend to read the documentation https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/sqlite.html

> Layer Creation Options
>
> LAUNDER=YES/NO: Controls whether layer and field names will be
> laundered for easier use in SQLite. Laundered names will be converted
> to lower case and some special characters(‘ - #) will be changed to
> underscores. Default to YES.

```
ogr2ogr -f "SQLite" -dsco SPATIALITE=YES  -lco LAUNDER=NO -oo X_POSSIBLE_NAMES=longitude -oo Y_POSSIBLE_NAMES=latitude casetest.sqlite casetest.csv

ogrinfo casetest.sqlite -al -so
INFO: Open of `casetest.sqlite'
      using driver `SQLite' successful.

Layer name: casetest
Geometry: Point
Feature Count: 2
Extent: (-46.643363, -23.555297) - (-46.635642, -23.547384)
Layer SRS WKT:
(unknown)
FID Column = OGC_FID
Geometry Column = GEOMETRY
Column1: String (0.0)
Column2: String (0.0)
latitude: Real (0.0)
longitude: Real (0.0)
```